Integral's Computation does not match WolframAlpha's result (numerical approximation)
I was given the following integral by a friend:
\begin{gather}
I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x) \sin(\sin x)}{x^2}e^{\cos x}dx
\end{gather}
I started out by rewriting the $\sin$ composition:
\begin{gather}
I = \Im \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \cdot e^{i\sin x}}{x^2}e^{\cos x}dx = \Im \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2}e^{e^{ix}}dx
\end{gather}
Utilizing the Taylor series for the exponential:
\begin{gather}
I = \Im \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2}e^{kix} dx
\end{gather}
The imaginary part of $e^{kix}$ is simply $\sin kx$. Since $x \in \mathbb R$, this won't affect other parts of the integrand:
\begin{gather}
I = \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin kx}{x^2}dx
\end{gather}
Define the parametric integral:
\begin{gather}
J_k(t) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x \sin kx}{x^2}e^{-tx}dx
\end{gather}
Thus, the target integral may be written as:
\begin{gather}
I = \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{J_k(0)}{k!} = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{J_k(0)}{k!}
\end{gather}
Also note that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} J_k(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{d}{d\tau}J_k(\tau = t) = 0$ for all $k$. Differentiating under the integral with respect to $t$ twice we have:
\begin{gather}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}J_k(t) = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\sin x \sin kx \, dx
\end{gather}
What follows are elementary integrals, and the requisite value turns out to be
\begin{gather}
J_k(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{gather}
for $k \geq 1$. Plugging this back into the original expression for $I$, we have:
\begin{gather}
I = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}(e - 1) \approx 2.6991
\end{gather}
However, WolframAlpha reports the answer to be approximately $2.69184$. Am I missing a trivial factor here?

Your result is perfectly correct. The problem is related to very slow convergence and the highly oscillatory integrand,

By the way $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (x) \sin (k x)}{x^2} ,dx=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(\sqrt{(k+1)^2}-\sqrt{(k-1)^2}\right)$$ would make the solution a bit faster. Nice work, indeed !

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for letting me know! How would that result be derived without differentiating under the integral?

I hope that what I wrote is clear. Cheers :-)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin (\sin x)}{x^2} e^{\cos x} d x 
= & \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \Im (e^{i \sin x}) e^{\cos x}}{x^2} d x \\
= &\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \Im (e^{e^ {i x}})}{x^2} d x \\
= &\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2} \Im \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{i x}\right)^n}{n!} d x \\
= & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin (n x)}{x^2} d x \\=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n-1) x-\cos (n+1) x}{x^2} d x \\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_0^{\infty} \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \frac{\sin (y x)}{x} d y d x \\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (y x)}{x} d x d y \\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n!} \int_{n-1}^{n+1} \frac{\pi}{2} d y \\
=&\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \\
=&\frac{\pi}{2}(e-1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

This is not an answer.
$$I_k=\int \frac{\sin (x) \sin (k x)}{x^2} \,dx$$ Using the product to sum relation (this is the key)
$$\sin (x) \sin (k x)=\frac{1}{2} (\cos ((k-1) x)-\cos ((k+1) x))$$ So two integrals looking like
$$J_a=\int \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2} \,dx=a\int\frac{\cos (t)}{t^2}\,dt$$
One integration by parts
$$\int\frac{\cos (t)}{t^2}\,dt=-\frac{\cos (t)}{t}-\int\frac{\sin (t)}{t} \,dt=-\frac{\cos (t)}{t}-\text{Si}(t)$$
Recombining and back to $x$
$$I_k=-\frac{\sin (x) \sin (k x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2} ((k+1) \,\text{Si}((k+1) x)-(1-k)\, \text{Si}((1-k) x))$$
Using the bounds
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (x) \sin (k x)}{x^2} \,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}  \left(\sqrt{(k+1)^2}-\sqrt{(k-1)^2}\right)$$ which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ if $k \ge 1$.

Hello, thank you for this; I considered this approach myself, however the intermediate step that included the improper integral of $\cos (x)/x^2$ didn't converge, which was why I abandoned the approach.
